# Optimum algorithm for overlapping pictures

Tags: algorithm

I want an algorithm with complexity less than O(n^2) for the following problem.

There are N number of pictures of same height but different width which are overlapping each other.  You will be provided starting and ending coordinate along x-axis for all the pictures. You have to tell, how many pictures are visible from top. As, heights are same, you don't have to consider anything about height or anything along y-axis.

I have solved it using an algorithm that is almost brute-forcing and resulting O(n^2) complexity. I need some better method.

Order of giving input will represent z-order. 1st picture will be in lowermost postion and 2nd picture will be over 1st picture, 3rd picture will be over 2nd picture and so on.. (You can think about a vertical stack where the pictures are being pushed one by one)

Comment: What about Z-order? If you had e.g. `(x:0; w:100)` and then `(x:0; w:50)`, `(x:50:w:50)` does #1 obscure #2 and #3, or vice versa?

Comment: Actually, order of giving input will represent z-order. 1st picture will be in lowermost postion and 2nd picture will be over 1st picture, 3rd picture will be over 2nd picture and so on.. (You can think about a vertical stack where the pictures are being pushed one by one). I forgot to mention about z-order in the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Do you mean how many pictures are *entirely* visible, or how many are *partly* visible?

Comment: @j_random_hacker ,  both have to be counted i.e. number of entirely visible + partly visible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an **O(n log n)** algorithm.  The idea is that we represent each picture as a pair of transitions, one at its left edge and one at its right edge, with each transition consisting of a pair (i, x), to be interpreted as "When moving from left to right, picture i becomes visible at x".  We add pictures one at a time in bottom-to-top Z order, building up a list of these transitions that describes the current state as we go.  This list stores only "active" transitions -- that is, transitions that are not obscured by some higher picture.  This means that as well as adding two new transitions for the picture we are currently adding, we need to delete any transitions that are covered by it.  We store the active transition list in a self-balancing binary tree that keeps it ordered by x co-ord, and allows insertions and deletions in O(log n) time.

Let's call the x co-ords of picture i's left and right edges L(i) and R(i), respectively.  For a transition t = (i, x), we will write pic(t) to extract the picture index i and pos(t) to extract the x co-ord x.  We also want to be able to find, within the list (conceptually it's a list, though it's stored as a binary tree for efficient lookups) of active transitions, the rightmost active transition that occurs at or to the left of some given co-ord x: call this prec(x).  This can be found in O(log n) time.  Finally, given a transition t, we want to be able to find the next transition to its right: call this succ(t).  This can be extracted in O(log n) time too (and in fact in amortized O(1) time).

To avoid a corner case, we first of all imagine that there is some "background" picture on the bottom whose left and right co-ordinates are negative and positive infinity, respectively.  We assign this picture index -1.  All other pictures are indexed by their positions in the Z order (i.e. in input order).

Initially, the tree of active transitions will consist of just the background picture, which we can represent using the transitions (-1, -inf) and (-1, inf).  (It doesn't matter that the "end" transition is "back to itself", -1 -- all we care about is making sure that succ(t) will always return a value for any non-background picture.)  Then, for each picture i in turn:

1. Look up prec(L(i)).  Let this transition be t = (j, y).  (prec(L(i)) must return a value, since the background picture has a start transition at -inf.)
2. Set v = t.
3. If pos(y) < L(i) then set t = succ(t).
4. While pos(t) <= R(i):

   - Set u = succ(t).
   - If pos(t) < R(i) then set v = t.
   - Delete t from the active transition list (O(log n) time).
   - Set t = u.  (u is just a temporary variable to hold the next value of t.)
5. Insert (i, L(i)) into the active transition list to represent the start of picture i's visibility range.
6. The previous inner loop has left v at the last (rightmost) active transition with x co-ord < R(i).  The picture that this transition indicated will become visible at pos(v) is the picture that will resume being visible when picture i's span ends at R(i), so insert (pic(v), R(i)) into the active transition list to reflect this.

Steps 3 and 4 delete any covered-over transitions.  Although it might seem that this inner loop could lead to quadratic time, it doesn't, because *any inserted transition will be removed by this inner loop at most once* across the entire algorithm.  Only 2n transitions are ever inserted, so at most 2n transitions can ever be removed by this inner loop across all outer loop iterations.

By now, we will have an active transition list with at most 2n transitions that describes the visibility of all pictures.  Make a linear-time pass from left to right over this list, setting a flag visible[i] for each transition (i, x) that it contains.  Finally, count the number of pictures having their visible flags set: this is the answer.  (We need separate steps for this because a picture may become visible many times if many narrower pictures are on top of it.)